# Python: Extract the index value from the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause

Python:
I have an Array A2 with 3 rows & 2 col and A3 with 1row & 2 columns. Now, I want to print the index of both elements in A3 with respect to A2

Example

```
A2 = np.array([[0 6]
               [15 1]
                [1 15]]) 

A3 = [15 1]
```

Now, I want to write a code to print the position of both elements of A3 with respect to A2.

Expected output

(1,0)

Please help me with this in python

I tried to use

`np.argwhere(A3 == A2).squeeze()`

But this is giving me output as [1,0], [1,1]

Comment: Hi Akhilesh Arkala, and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you help me understand your question? "Now, I want to print the index of A3 with respect to A2" What do you mean? Your example with "expected output" does not help me that much.

Comment: Hi, @NerdOnTour I want to print the position of A3 element with respect to A2. as stated in my example [15 1] is lying at (1,1) position in the A2. Now, I want to print that as output.

Comment: So you're not searching for each of the numbers 15 and 1 on their own, but you're looking for the 2-elements array [15, 1] inside A2?

Comment: Yes, I'm searching for 2 elements of A3 in A2

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks for clarifying. I think it would be helpful for other users of the site if you can make the point as clear as possible in your question (by editing the question).

Comment: Again concerning your question: Will your array A3 always be of shape (2,) and A2 always be of shape (3,2)? Or will you need this with arrays of totally different shapes, too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241130/discussion-between-nerdontour-and-akhilesh-arkala).

Comment: Why is (1,1) the output you expect? I would expect (1,0).

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to find if the elements of array 2 are in array 1?

```
def search_two_elements_of_array_in_array(arr,arr2):
    """
    :return: index if two elements of arr are in arr2 numpy array and print index
    """
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] in arr2:
            print(i)
            return i
    return -1
```

Comment: Thanks for your code @Houssem, but this is giving me an error `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Hello @AkhileshArkala, try the new code snippet it will return True or False if the elements in arr are found in arr2

Comment: Thanks @Houssem, but I also want to print the index

Comment: @AkhileshArkala now it prints index

Answer (score 0):

This is not (yet) a full answer, but may already resolve some of your confusion.

**Why does `np.argwhere(A3 == A2).squeeze()` not do the job?**

The `==` operator can compare two arrays of the same shape. If they are not of the same shape, they are (if possible) broadcasted to match in shape. In this case, A3 is initially of shape `(2,)`, but broadcasted to shape `(3,2)` to match A2. `A3 == A2` is then an array of bools, indicating whether the element of `A2` is equal to the correspondent element of `A3` or not.
Therefore, this is what happens:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> A2 = np.array([[0, 6], [15, 1], [1, 15]])
>>> A3 = np.array([15, 1])
>>> 
>>> A2.shape
(3, 2)
>>> A3.shape
(2,)
>>> 
>>> A2 == A3
array([[False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False]])
```

With this in mind, you can understand what `argwhere` returns and why:

```py
>>> np.argwhere(A3==A2)
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

What your code did so far was not looking for the whole array `[15, 1]`, but for each occurence of `15` in the first column and for each occurence of `1` in the second column.