# Python: Extract the index value from the array by comparing from another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, where-clause

Python: I have an Array A1 with 3 rows & 2 col and A2 with 1row & 2 columns. Now, I want to print the index of both elements in A2 with respect to A1

Example

```
A1 = np.array([[0, 6], [15, 1], [1, 15]]) #shape (3,2)
A2 = np.array([15, 1]) #shape(2,)
```

Expected output
`(1,0)  #Index(position) of array [15,1] in A1`

I tried using
`np.argwhere(A2 == A1).squeeze()`

but its not working out as it is writing only A2[0] i.e, 15 instead of entire array [15,1]

Please help me with this in python.

Continuation:
[Python: Extract the index value from the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70332923/python-extract-the-index-value-from-the-array/70739595#70739595)

Comment: np.argwhere((A2 == A1).all(1)).squeeze()

Comment: You're welcome . Please consider [sharing your own answer and accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

A1 = np.array([[0, 6], [15, 1], [1, 15]]) #shape (3,2)
A2 = np.array([15, 1]) #shape(2,)

a = np.argwhere((A2 == A1).all(1)).squeeze()
print(a)
```

Output

```
(1,0)
```

This code works & checks all the elements in array A2 w.r.t A1 and prints its index thanks to @yann ziselman

Comment: Is this code complete? Maybe A1 and A2 should be added. Also np needs an import probably. Don't expect people know these.